# Invoke-Command fails with $env Variable fails when configuration is read from a file

Tags: json, powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to retrieve files from a remote system via PowerShell. In order to do this i utilize New- PSSession and Invoke-Command in this session.

`$latestFolder = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock{param($path) Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Name} -ArgumentList $path`

If i set path to `$Path = "$env:SystemRoot\System32"` it works just fine, but if i set it to a string read from a configuration file (json) it gives me the weirdest problems. One is that it cannot find the parameter **-Directory**, if i omit the -Directory and -Name parameters the error message is **Ein Laufwerk mit dem Namen "$env" ist nicht vorhanden.** Roughly translatet to **A drive named "$env" is not available.**

The configuration file looks like this:

```
{
    "File": [
        {
            "Name": "TEST",
            "Active": true,
            "Path": "$env:SystemRoot\\System32"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Powershell script is the following:

```
$logFilePath = Join-Path (get-item $PSScriptRoot).FullName "Test.json"
$logConfig = Get-Content -Path $logFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json

$windowsUser = "username"
$windowsUserPassword = "password"
$windowsUserPasswordsec = $windowsUserPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Server = "server"

$Path = "$env:SystemRoot\System32"
$Path = $logConfig.File[0].Path

$sessioncred = new-object -typeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $windowsUser, $windowsUserPasswordsec
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $sessioncred -Authentication "Kerberos"

$latestFolder = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock{param($path) Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Name} -ArgumentList $Path
$latestFolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitely expand the string read from the `Path` element in the Json file.

This should do it:

```
$Path = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($logConfig.File[0].Path)
```

An alternative could be by using `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$Path = Invoke-Expression ('"{0}"' -f $logConfig.File[0].Path)
```

Comment: The alternative worked, it is now used like this
 ```$latestFolder = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock{param($path) Get-ChildItem (Invoke-Expression ('"{0}"' -f $path)) -Directory -Name} -ArgumentList $logConfig.File[0].Path```

Comment: @xBarns Good to hear. The first one worked for me too in PowerShell 5.1, but I have noticed there may be quirks in other versions.